# '+' String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, excel-formula, amortization

this is a simple calculation formula im doing trying ruby for the first time and stuck on a simple error bt need some guidance

```
#input
loan_amount = 0
rate = 0
period = 0

#output
monthly_payment = 0

print "Enter loan_amount: "
loan_amount = gets.to_f
print "Enter rate: "
rate = gets.to_f
print "Enter period: "
period = gets.to_f
```

## Error when i calculate the formula I end up getting this [undefined method rate for main:Object (NoMethodError)]

```
monthly_payment = loan_amount((rate(1 + rate)**period)/(1 + rate)**period - 1)

puts "#{monthly_payment}"
```

Comment: You have to convert strings to numbers before, e.g. `'12'.to_f`. `period`, `loan_amount ` and `roi` are candidates for the conversion.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a gem called Exonio: https://github.com/Noverde/exonio .
This gem implements some of the Excel financials methods like: PMT, IPMT, PV, NPER...

Answer (score 1):

Method `gets` always return string

```
loan_amount = gets
=> "1"
```

You should transform strings to numbers before calculation:

```
loan_amount = gets
loan_amount = loan_amount.to_f
...
```

Comment: You use `rate` as method here `rate(1 + rate)`, first occurance. I guess you missed an operator.

Comment: Without providing a full code source I will not be able to figure out an error.

Comment: solved the error....i was using rate as a method and missed the operator. Thanks for the help sschmeck